# Can't find class from maven dependency project

Tags: java, maven, jar, intellij-idea, dependencies

[CLOSED - I had to move classes from test/java to main/java and update the maven repository via the IDE "maven options"]

I'm new to maven and inexperienced with java development. I'm using IntelliJ Idea as IDE. I'm using Maven 3.0.4.

I created a "project A" and a "project B", each with some classes. Now when I try to create a dependency in *project A* to a class in *project B* I can't seem to find any classes that are part of *project B*. When I check the maven repository I can see that a .jar file is created based on *project B*.

To clarify: when adding a dependency to *project B* I **do** find an artifact called "project B" but I **cannot** find any classes that are part of *project B*.

It doesn't seem like I can access and use any of the classes that are part of *project B* inside *project A* which would make this installation worthless.

--

Please tell me what information I should include for you to help me solve this problem.

[EDIT] Here is the *project A*'s pom with a dependency on *project B*. However I either don't understand how to use it in my project or it doesn't work. While I can use IntelliJ's functionality to find and add the artifact, intelliJ can't seem to find any classes that are part of *project B* (while it does find classes that are part of other pre-defined packages in the maven repository):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>planet</groupId>
    <artifactId>planet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>toolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>toolbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: The poms, at the least, the relevant parts (e.g., at least the artifact info, and A's dependency on B). How you're adding the dependency. What it means when you say "cannot find any classes that are part of project B".

Comment: A's dependency on B doesn't exit in the pom yet. It's what I'm trying to achieve. IntelliJ has a function to add dependencies and searches either by artifact or class. That's what I mean by "cannot find any classes that are part of *project B*".

Comment: Just add the dependency; I don't know how it does its class search--check the docs.

Comment: What does `mvn clean install` say when you execute it on the command line?

Comment: Executing mvn clean install helped me solve the problem. It was successful but it seems I overlooked a warning that there were no classes to compile and the jar file was empty. The problem was that I put my classes inside test/java instead of main/java. After updating the repository I was able to find *project B* classes and get it all to work.

It was silly but this did help me find the answer. Running it in the command line just made me notice what I overlooked in the IDE.

Comment: Voted to close, as that seems to be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to move my classes from test/java to main/java. Silly, but it took me a whole day to realise this. This only worked after updating the repository in "maven options" via the IDE.

Comment: The classes being imported or the classes doing the importing?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>toolbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>toolbox</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Works for me :)